# How to control pytest-cov (or generally any pytest plugin) from my own plugin

Tags: python, plugins, pytest, pytest-cov

I have a plugin `myplugin` with the following behavior: When calling `pytest ... --myplugin=X` it should trigger the same behavior as `pytest ... --cov=X --cov-report=json`.

I'm still new to `pytest` and while my implementation technically works, I feel very uncomfortable with it because my implementations seems to break `pytest` behavior (see below) and I cannot manage to find general enough information on the pytest plugin concept in the pytest API reference or tutorials/videos to understand my mistake.

As I'm eager to learn, my **question** here is twofold

- Concrete: What am I doing wrong in terms of pytest plugin design?
- General: Are there better approaches for controlling another plugin? If yes, how would one apply them to `pytest_cov`?

We start with an example test project

```py
# myproject/src/__init__.py

def func():
    return 42

# myproject/test_src.py

import src

def test_src():
    assert src.func() == 42
```

Then there is the plugin

```py
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    group = parser.getgroup('myplugin')
    group.addoption(
        '--myplugin',
        action='store',
        dest='myplugin_source',
        default=None,
    )

def _reconfigure_cov_parameters(options):
    options.cov_source = [options.myplugin_source]
    options.cov_report = {
        'json': None
    }

# FIXME this solution to control pytest_cov strongly relies on their implementation details
# - because pytest_cov uses the same hook without hookwrapper,
#   we are guaranteed to come first
# - we modify the config parameters, hence strongly rely on their interface
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_load_initial_conftests(early_config, parser, args):
    print('\ncode point 1')
    print('early_config.known_args_namespace.cov_source', early_config.known_args_namespace.cov_source)
    print('early_config.known_args_namespace.cov_report', early_config.known_args_namespace.cov_report)
    print('early_config.known_args_namespace.myplugin_source', early_config.known_args_namespace.myplugin_source)

    if early_config.known_args_namespace.myplugin_source is not None:
        _reconfigure_cov_parameters(early_config.known_args_namespace)

    print('\ncode point 2')
    print('early_config.known_args_namespace.cov_source', early_config.known_args_namespace.cov_source)
    print('early_config.known_args_namespace.cov_report', early_config.known_args_namespace.cov_report)
    print('early_config.known_args_namespace.myplugin_source', early_config.known_args_namespace.myplugin_source)

    yield

def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    print('\ncode point 3')
    print('session.config.option.cov_source=', session.config.option.cov_source)
    print('session.config.option.cov_report', session.config.option.cov_report)
    print('session.config.option.myplugin_source=', session.config.option.myplugin_source)
```

When I run the plugin, it technically does what it should, `cov` behaves exactly like I want it producing the `json` output.

However, if I look at the debug output, it is as follows (truncated to relevant details):

- scenario 1 without `myplugin`

```
$ python -m pytest -vs test_src.py --cov=./src --cov-report=html

code point 1
early_config.known_args_namespace.cov_source ['./src']
early_config.known_args_namespace.cov_report {'html': None}
early_config.known_args_namespace.myplugin_source None

code point 2
early_config.known_args_namespace.cov_source ['./src']
early_config.known_args_namespace.cov_report {'html': None}
early_config.known_args_namespace.myplugin_source None

plugins: cov-4.1.0, myplugin-0.1.0

code point 3
session.config.option.cov_source= ['./src']
session.config.option.cov_report {'html': None}
session.config.option.myplugin_source= None
```

- scenario 2 with `myplugin`

```
$ python -m pytest -vs --myplugin=./src

code point 1
early_config.known_args_namespace.cov_source []
early_config.known_args_namespace.cov_report {}
early_config.known_args_namespace.myplugin_source ./src

code point 2
early_config.known_args_namespace.cov_source ['./src']
early_config.known_args_namespace.cov_report {'json': None}
early_config.known_args_namespace.myplugin_source ./src

plugins: cov-4.1.0, myplugin-0.1.0

code point 3
session.config.option.cov_source= []
session.config.option.cov_report {}
session.config.option.myplugin_source= ./src

Coverage JSON written to file coverage.json
```

So what puzzles me here, is that `myplugin` seems to break `pytest`s processing of the `cov_source` option so that my manipulations of `cov_` options in `early_config.known_args_namespace` are not correctly transferred to `session.config`. Even more surprising is that `cov` still sees my changes.

That is due to the fact, that `cov` seems to mainly rely on `early_config.known_args_namespace`, maybe that is a non-standard paradigm which I shouldn't have followed.

Details:

- plugin structure taken from https://github.com/pytest-dev/cookiecutter-pytest-plugin and installed via `pip install -e`.
- `Python 3.10.12`
- `pytest-7.3.1`
- `cov-4.1.0`

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the `pytest-cov` repo it seems your implementation is just about the only way (that I can tell) to modify the parameters before the plugin is configured. Why the debug print outs are different I'm unsure of.

However, I'm going to suggest an alternate approach that may or may not work for your use case, but *does* solve the debug issue.

Rather than modify the current session, the below code will completely restart the session instead. This also has the potential benefit of relying on the external api (rather than the internal one) which is probably less likely to change.

```
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_load_initial_conftests(early_config, parser, args):
    session_restart = False
    
    for idx, value in enumerate(args):
        if "myplugin" in value:
            args[idx] = value.replace("myplugin", "cov")
            args.append("--cov-report=json")
            session_restart = True
    
    if session_restart:
        return_code = pytest.main(args)
        exit(return_code)
        
    yield
```

Comment: Thank You, but this won't work: If You run `python -m pytest --myplugin=./src.py` it will not trigger `pytest-cov` and if You run `python -m pytest --myplugin=./src.py --cov=foo/bar` then `pytest-cov` will use `foo/bar`.

Comment: @flonk you're right, my fault. I was focusing on the printouts and didn't realize it wasn't being executed. However, I modified my answer with a different approach that may work.